# What their is need to write "var nav;" if we are not saving any data in this variable?

Tags: javascript

I was doing a course on Udacity on jQuery. There I came over a tutorial where they use to write "var nav;" without storing any data in this variable.

Here's the code:

```
var nav;
nav = // your code goes here!
console.log(nav);
```

Why not simply write the following code:

```
var nav = // your code goes here!
console.log(nav);
```

Following is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You should probably ask them. There are many ways to write a code to get a result.

Comment: It is best practice to declare a variable in javascript first.  But you could have also done `var nav =// your code goes here`

Comment: No technical difference if there's no intervening code. But systems that evaluate code for you may have a different set of requirements.

Comment: Probably to avoid anyone messing with he `var nav` part. If you don't have to make edits to that line, it's more likely that it stays as it is.

Comment: What happens when you try both scenarios? You could have answered your own question by doing a simple exercise.

Comment: Can anybody explain why stackoverflow deducted my 6 Reputation for asking this question? I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They separated the declaration of the variable from the part you would edit. Outside of code styling choices, this separation decreases the likelihood your code changes would affect the declared variable name. Which would break the intended functionality of the next line.